# How can I fix this? " HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED after normal block.. CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer "

Tags: c++, pointers, sfml, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

I had a program working good (without prompting errors) using references, but I decided to use a pointer-to-pointer array allocated on virtual memory, because I can use a variable as the size of the array.

The error prompts when I break the `while (m_Window.isOpen())` loop, in other words when I close the game window and the game is finished. I have noticed that the program breaks when I try to erase the virtual memory in the `Engine::cleanVirtualMemory()` function. I have noticed that it is there because I have put two flags (`cout << "running1" << endl;` and `cout << "running2" << endl`) and I can show just the first flag.

Then it prompts a window with the following message:

> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED after normal block.. CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer

main.cpp

```
#include "Engine.h"
using namespace sf;

int main(){

    Engine Motor;
    Motor.run();
    Motor.cleanVirtualMemory();
}
```

Engine.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "StructureBuilder.h"

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

class Engine{
private:

    // Lots of variables ....
    Vector2i m_ArenaSize;
    Vector2f * vectorStructureArray = new Vector2f[m_ArenaSize.y * m_ArenaSize.x * 4];
    int** logicStructureArray = new int*[m_ArenaSize.y];
    // Lots of variables ....

    //Gameloop
    void Input();
    void Update(dtAsSeconds);
    void Draw();

public:

    Engine();
    void run();
    void cleanVirtualMemory();

};
```

Engine.cpp

```
#include "Engine.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace sf;


Engine::Engine() {

/// lots of variables and data ...

/// Making arena
m_ArenaSize = Vector2i(10, 10);
StructureBuilder(arenaStructures, vectorStructureArray, logicStructureArray,  m_ArenaSize);
}


void Engine::run() {

//Timing
Clock clock;
while (m_Window.isOpen()) {

    // Each time clock restarted, dt = time elapse (from 0 to now, then clock = 0)
    Time dt = clock.restart();

    // Convert time elapse to seconds
    double dtAsSeconds = dt.asSeconds();
   
    //  Call each part of the game in turn
    Input();
    Update(dtAsSeconds);
    Draw();
    }
}

void Engine::cleanVirtualMemory() {
    // Deallocate Virtual Memory
    
    // first flag
    cout << "running1" << endl;

    for (int i = m_ArenaSize.x - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        delete[] logicStructureArray[i];
    }
    delete[] logicStructureArray;
    logicStructureArray = NULL;
    delete[] vectorStructureArray;
    vectorStructureArray = NULL;

   // second flag
   cout << "running2" << endl;
}
```

StructureBuilder.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

Vector2i StructureBuilder(VertexArray& rVA, Vector2f* rA, int** rLA, Vector2i ArenaSize);
```

In the following code, you can see where I use pointers, I have erased code just to simplify.

StructureBuilder.cpp

```
#include "StructureBuilder.h"

Vector2i StructureBuilder(VertexArray& rVA, Vector2f* rA, int** rLA, Vector2i ArenaSize) {

    //Set map properties and VertexArrayType
    double tileSize = 100;
    double Height = ArenaSize.y * tileSize;
    double angle = 30;
    int offset = 0;
    int Primitive = 4;
    int currentVertex = 0;

    rVA.setPrimitiveType(Quads);
    rVA.resize(ArenaSize.x * ArenaSize.y * 4);

    // First build graphically our map structures's using char strings 
    string stringArray[10]; 
    stringArray[0] = "1000000000";
    stringArray[1] = "0000000000";
    stringArray[2] = "0000010000";
    stringArray[3] = "0000000000";
    stringArray[4] = "0000000000";
    stringArray[5] = "0000000000";
    stringArray[6] = "0000000000";
    stringArray[7] = "0000000000";
    stringArray[8] = "0000000000";
    stringArray[9] = "0000000000";

    // Convert stringArray to charArray, finally charArray to intArray
    char** charArray = new char*[ArenaSize.y]; 

    Vector2f Vector1;
    Vector2f Vector2;
    Vector2f Vector3;
    Vector2f Vector4;

    for (int i = 0; i < ArenaSize.x; i++) {
       charArray[i] = new char[ArenaSize.x];
       rLA[i] = new int[ArenaSize.x];
        
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ArenaSize.x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ArenaSize.y; j++) {
            charArray[j][i] = stringArray[j][i];
            rLA[j][i] = charArray[j][i] - 48;

            // Check when we have a value greater or equal to 1, if yes build a structure.
            if (rLA[j][i] == 1) {

                
                Vector1 = Vector2f(Value..., Value...);// in order to understand I dont put the whole calculation here
                Vector2 = Vector2f(Value..., Value ...); // is just trigonometry to find vertex
                Vector3 = Vector2f(Value..., Value ...);
                Vector4 = Vector2f(Value..., Value ...);


                rVA[currentVertex + 0].position = Vector1;
                rVA[currentVertex + 1].position = Vector2;
                rVA[currentVertex + 2].position = Vector3;
                rVA[currentVertex + 3].position = Vector4;

                rVA[currentVertex + 0].texCoords = Vector2f(42, 0); // coords on my spritesheet
                rVA[currentVertex + 1].texCoords = Vector2f(86, 24);
                rVA[currentVertex + 2].texCoords = Vector2f(42, 49);
                rVA[currentVertex + 3].texCoords = Vector2f(0, 24);

                rA[currentVertex + 0] = Vector1; //Later I use this to tell the program where to construct restrictions (where the player can't move)
                rA[currentVertex + 1] = Vector2;
                rA[currentVertex + 2] = Vector3;
                rA[currentVertex + 3] = Vector4;
            }
           
            currentVertex = currentVertex + Primitive;
        }
    }

    // Deallocate Virtual Memory
    for (int i = ArenaSize.x - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        delete[] charArray[i];
    }
    delete[] charArray;
    charArray = NULL;


    return ArenaSize;
}
```

Comment: Take a close look at `char** charArray = new char*[ArenaSize.y];` and `for (int i = 0; i < ArenaSize.x; i++) { charArray[i] = new char[ArenaSize.x];` Seems the for loop bound should be `ArenaSize.y` doesn't it?

Comment: should be, but ArenaSize.y is equal to ArenaSize.x

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at our page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I don't think the code you've posted is minimal, but is it at least complete? That is, if I copy and paste it, will it reproduce the error? I'd rather not go to the trouble if it won't.

Comment: life would get way easier if you used std::vector instead of 'new' arrays.  Your IDE would almost certainly break into your program if you access elements outside the bounds, which is almost certainly what you are doing here.

Comment: `int** logicStructureArray = new int*[m_ArenaSize.y];` -- Usage of `new[]` to create dynamic arrays in user-based C++ programs is discouraged in this day and age of C++.  That should be `std::vector<std::vector<int>> logicStructureArray;` and in the constructor initialization, `logicStructreArray(m_ArenaSize.y);` .  The same thing with the `char**` -- that could have simply been `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: *but i decided to use pointer to pointer array allocated on virtual memory cause I can put a variable as size of array* -- I guess you missed what `std::vector` does for you.  It does everything you're trying to do, with the difference being that vector doesn't make mistakes managing memory.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have replaced those dynamic pointers array, and I have used vectors containers, were easiest to use them and i hadn't errors. My project now is running good. My problem was solved. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the declaration of the `Engine` class.

```
class Engine{
private:

    // Lots of variables ....
    Vector2i m_ArenaSize;
    Vector2f * vectorStructureArray = new Vector2f[m_ArenaSize.y * m_ArenaSize.x * 4];
```

The first member of your `Engine` class is called `m_ArenaSize`. This is the first class member that will get constructed when an `Engine` gets constructed. That's how object construction works in C++: when a new object gets constructed, all of the new object's members get constructed in declaration order.

The second member of your `Engine` class is this `vectorStructureArray` pointer. It will be allocated to point to an array, with dynamic size, that gets `new`ed using two of the constructed `m_ArenaSize`'s own members, `x` and `y`.

And now, let's take a look at `Engine`'s constructor:

```
Engine::Engine() {
```

All right. That's your constructor. So, according to our plan, `m_ArenaSize` is going to get default-constructed since it is not explicitly constructed, in `Engine`'s constructor's initialization section (there is none, here). If you investigate what `m_ArenaSize`'s default constructor does you will discover that it defaults `x` and `y` to 0.

And that's what's going to construct the `vectorStructureArray` pointer, as the 2nd order of business of `Engine`'s default initialization. And, because its `x` and `y` are 0, the pointer will point to a grand total of 0 values.

```
m_ArenaSize = Vector2i(10, 10);
```

And only now the default-constructed `m_ArenaSize` gets replaced with a different subject, with different `x` and `y` values. The shown code clearly expects the pointer to get reallocated, to reflect `m_ArenaSize`'s new `x` and `y` values,. However C++ does not work this way. `vectorStructureArray` has already been constructed. It's not going to get constructed again simply because a different class member gets replaced. Subsequent code's assumption is the new `x` and `y` values, and this results in fairly obvious memory corruption.

The same exact bug occurs with `logicStructureArray`, too.

These are just the first two major bugs in the shown code regarding memory allocation. There are several ways to fix them, but the easiest way to fix bugs is to make it logically impossible for them to happen in the first place. It is logically impossible for `new` and `delete`-related bugs to occur if they are never used. Modern C++ code rarely uses `new` and `delete`, but rather employs the services of the C++ library's many containers.

Here, both pointers can be simply replaced by `std::vector`, with its `resize()` member taking care of allocating both vectors' sizes. And, as extra bonus, all allocated memory gets automatically freed, automatically preventing all memory leaks.

Replacing all the error-prone `new` and `delete` logic with `std::vector` will fix all memory-related issues in the shown code, the only thing you will have to make sure is that the vectors are correctly `resize`()d.

Comment: Varshvchik 
Thanks for answer my question, I have replaced those array pointer to vectors, an that's right does the same same thing like dynamic array pointer, just that was easy to write without errors. 

I have replaced to:
_std::vector<Vector2f> vectorStructureVect;_
_std::vector<std::vector<int>> logicStructureVect;_

On my funtions arguments I have taken those vectors container as reference again.
In order to resize those container I use this sytaxis;
_rV.resize(ArenaSize.x * ArenaSize.y * 4);_
_rLV.resize(ArenaSize.x, std::vector<int>(ArenaSize.y)); // 2D vector container_

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track.